# System.InvalidCastException thrown after a certain quantity of variable uses

Tags: c#, casting

IDE: Visual Studio
Language: C#
DB: MSSQL

I am reading MSSQL DB and storing the records to a custom list for needed processing.  Initially I was getting cast exception when trying to assign the values from the DB to the variables.  This seemed understandable, though I found out that it would work fine for the first 2 records it read, though the third record it tried to handle, it would throw the cast error.  I started troubleshooting deeper and noticed that it seems to throw this cast exception always at a specified line of code, or number of variable assignments.  I tested this by simply assigning a string value "" to the string variable, and the error is thrown for that assignment.  If I change the order of the variables assigned, the variable I formerly had an issue with is assigned fine, though the 5th variable always has the issue.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgET9.png)

Comment: Is that code compiled for RELEASE or with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Just how the default is when the Visual Studio IDE is installed.

Comment: The reason I ask is that the stack trace shown in that dialog doesn't show line numbers, so debug information seems to be missing. This also means the exact line being highlighted by the debugger might be the wrong one, it might be the previous or next line depending on the exact location of the exception.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you're both right.  I moved all the DateTime variables all to the end and the error is throwing around that position now.  This is super helpful.

Comment: If it is the datetime conversions, try doing `record[2].GetType()` and check what it returns. Most likely that and `[3]` is not really a DateTime.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Don't add screenshots of code and errors, copy them to question.